# jQuery: Add class to <tr> on mouseover in order to style <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, addclass

I'm trying to append a class to a `<tr>` when mousing over (highlight), in which I will be styling the child `<td>`'s. Just adding the desired effect (background color) on the `<tr>` won't do, because of the bg properties of the internal `<td>`'s.

I've made sure jquery is running, and I'm using 1.9 min.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('table tr').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

I have the corresponding `.hightlight` class setup in CSS as in `.highlight td {}` to style the `<td>`'s when the highlight class is added to the `<tr>`.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I've tested that the `<td>`'s are styled correctly by manually adding `class="highlight"` to the `<tr>`, and that works.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/WUMwr/

Comment: Nothing, so far as I can see! Your script should work fine. Have you put it into the bottom of the page? (Or if you must put it in the header, is it wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ })`)

Comment: I guess it should indeed work, but just doesn't on the doc I'm working on. Could be other stuff interfering, idk.

Comment: Also, if that's not the problem, is that table created dynamically (after the above script is called)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only fact that comes to my mind is placing your code in the [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("highlight");
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

... and maybe using more handy [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method instead.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B2Rnz/

Answer (score 1):

You could define only one `.highlight` declaration and apply it to the `<td>`:

```
 $(function() {
     $('table tr').on('mouseover', 'td', function(){
           $(this).addClass('highlight');
       }).on('mouseout', 'td', function(){
           $(this).removeClass('highlight');
       });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, iOraelosi.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no more logic involved you can also use plain CSS:

```
tr:hover td {
    background: #333;
}
```

Comment: For backward compatibility.

Comment: From what I can tell, some of the older ones doesn't support hover on non anchor elements.

Comment: @Jasd Yeah... Someone still uses that damned IE6, which supports `:hover` only for `<a>` elements.